# Random "splitting up" of integer value in Java

Tags: java, random

Interesting question, hope someone has an idea how to do this in Java. I have
a fixed integer value x, that I want to represent by a sum of integers x1, x2, ...,xn
such that the following holds:

```
x = x1 + x2 + ... + xn;
```

For example, lets assume n=3 and x= 10

```
10 = 5 + 3 + 2;
```

The thing is, the x1,x2, ... xn shares should be uniformely distributed, and everytime I want to "split" the value x into the different shares, they should be different.

Anyone an idea how do could be done?

Thanks,
Patrick

Comment: what do you mean by 'uniformely distributed'? do you mean if possible, x1 != x2 !=x3...!= xn  ?

Comment: your equation is confusing, x1 + x2 suggests x * 1 and x * 2, but you're equating them to x.

Comment: whats the uniformity in splitting ...

Comment: would `10 = 25 + 75 + (-90)` also be possible?

Comment: By unformely distributed I mean that the possibility for any value xi in the range between 0 and x should be equal to represent a "share" in the addition that makes up the value of x

Comment: x1 does not mean x*1, you should regard it as an index, like x_1, x_2 etc. if this makes more sense

Comment: It does not really matter which language you want to do it in because it is primarily logical problem. And you did **not** define it completely and/or correctly. What is the goal? The **fewer** or the **most** addends? The **most of unique** addends? Something else?

Comment: jlordo: no, that should not be possible, only the addition operation is allowed to make up the final value from the different shares

Comment: 9 = (8 + 1) = (5 + 4) = (4 + 3 + 2) + (5 + 3 + 1)... Which is the right combination/answer for you?  You should really define your question better.

Comment: @Patrick above example only uses the addition operator, `-90` is a negative number.

Comment: None of them are right, one requirement is that it should be different each time you run it. Maybe it's better to compute all possible combinations.

Comment: @jlordo you didn't specify that they had to be positive integers, you ARE only using the addition operator if your value is negative.

Comment: @Patrick in that case it is not always possible. for `2` you can't find two integers `x1, x2` such `0<x1,x2<2, x1!=x2 and 2=x1+x2`. For any `n` there are no `n` integers, in other words. Even stricter, for any `n`, there are no more than `-1 + sqtr(1 + 8n)/2` split parts.

Comment: Although in the end you would have to implement that in Java (or whatever language), I think you have to first think about the maths for a bit. I suggest moving this question to [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

This works, the idea is to take random numbers with maximum cap x - (n -i) i.e first element must be capped to 8 to avoid next numbers becoming zero. I am assuming positive numbers are required whose sum is x.

```
Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());        
for (int i = 0; i < n -1; i++) {
   int j = random.nextInt(x - (n -i)) + 1;
   System.out.println(j);
   x -= j;
}
System.out.println(x);
```

Comment: I think OP wants unique numbers, so no addend can occur twice.

Comment: That code runs into a trouble, if `random.nextInt(n)` returns `n-1`. All next generated `j` values will be `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, and also probably not very efficient, but should work:

```
public static int[] sumNumbers(int number, int parts) {
    int[] result = new int[parts];
    int sum = 0;
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 1; i < result.length; i++) {
        // here is the uneffecient part:
        int rand = random.nextInt(number);
        if (sum + rand < number) {
            result[i] = rand;
            sum += rand;
        } else {
            i--;
        }
    }
    result[0] = number - sum;
    return result;
}
```

It could be ineffecient because you could have following case:
You are splitting 100 into 25 numbers. Lets say the randomly chosen first 5 of them add up to a number near to 100, then you'd have to wait for the rest of the 20 numbers to randomly be very small.

Comment: That code doesn't produce different split values, as requested. Also, it may run into an infinite (=unnecessary long) loop.

Comment: what do you mean by _different split values_? I thought `n` and `x` are given? I have already stated, that it **could** run a long time.

Comment: What if an argument is illegal? Or your rand is 0 each time? Then result[0] contains the number itself?

Comment: Sure, he has to check the arguments. Now i know what you mean with _different split values_. How would he _split_ 2 into 2 numbers without having same split values or the number itself and a trailing 0?

Answer (score -1):

I did something like that:

```
  int remainder = 0;
  int n = 3;
  int max = 2000;

  for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
  {
    int ct = 0;

    if(i < n)
      ct = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, (max - remainder));
    else
      ct = max - remainder;

    System.out.println("Value " + i + " :" + ct);

    remainder += contCt;
  }
```